# Change CSS Class on load

Tags: jquery, css, sass

On my page I have a header such as

```
<header class="headerMain"> 
  <-- stuff goes here -->
</header>
```

When my page loads, I would like to change the class from headerMain to headerManager, headerSuper, and so on based on the users role. How can I change the class to be used when the page is loaded?

I tried:

```
(function ($) {
   if(Role == "Manager") 
   {
       document.getElementsByClassName("headerMain").toggleClass("headerManager");
   }
})
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Where is `Role` defined? I would suggest doing this with a Server Side Scripting instead of Client Scripting. Also: `$(".headerMain").removeClass("headerMain").addClass("headerManager");`

Comment: @Twisty it's in a variable that's passed in. I just need to change the class so the header changes based off of the role.

Comment: There is no `getElementByClassName`

Comment: @JustWantsToCode again, still think Server side is the way to go. If it's in the JS, then a Bad Actor could potentially edit and change the class manually to try and trick your script.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, you can perform the following.

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(".headerMain").removeClass("headerMain").addClass("header" + Role);
});
```

If `Role` is one of the following values:

- Main
- Manager
- Super

Then the class will be updated to match the Role.

Personally, I would separate the Class name. Start with a base HTML like:

```
<header class="header"> 
  <-- stuff goes here -->
</header>
```

In this way you can simply add the Role when the page loads.

```
$("header.header").addClass(Role);
```

Your Class is then `header Main` or `header Super` from the get go. Adjust your CSS to match: `.header.Main` and `.header.Super` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<header class="dynamicClass headerMain"> 
  <-- stuff goes here -->
</header>
<script>
    $( function() {
        var Role = 'Manager';
        $(".dynamicClass").removeClass('headerMain headerManager headerSuper');
        if(Role == "Manager"){
            $(".dynamicClass").addClass('headerManager');
        }else if(Role == "Super"){
            $(".dynamicClass").addClass('headerSuper');
        }else{
            $(".dynamicClass").addClass('headerMain');
        }
    })
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Html Code :

```
<header class="dynamicClass headerMain"> 

</header>
```

Jquery Code :

```
var Role = "Main";
 
 // Function to remove class start with 
  $.fn.removeClassStartingWith = function (filter) {
    $(this).removeClass(function (index, className) {
        return (className.match(new RegExp("\\S*" + filter + "\\S*", 'g')) || []).join(' ')
    });
    return this;
};

// Doucument ready use on load page always
 $(document).ready(function(){
 //Remove Class start with header
 $(".dynamicClass").removeClassStartingWith('header');

//Add Class By Role
 $(".dynamicClass").addClass('header'+ Role);
 })
```